# How to solve such complicated integration

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am trying to solve the following integral but not getting it correctly:

$P = \int_0^\infty y^{m_1-1}\exp(-\frac{m_1}{\Omega_1}y)(\frac{m_2}{\Omega_2}-sy)^{-m_2}\text{d}y$

where $m_1, \Omega_1, m_2, \Omega_2$ and $s$ are constants.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are $m_1$ and $m_2$ integers? In which case, it could be possible to expand the term $(m_2/\Omega_2 - sy)^{-m_2}$into a sum, swap the sum and integral sign, and you end up with a bunch of integrals of the form $\int y^s exp(-\alpha y) \text{d}y$, which is essentially the gamma function. It's not a very nice answer though, I'm sure someone will have a more elegant solution

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply sir.... here $m_1$, $m_2$ are not always integer.... the essential condition for $m_1$, $m_2$ is $m_1$, $m_2$ $\geq$ 0.5.

Comment: Mathematica can solve. Solution with `Gamma` and `Hypergeometric` function.

Comment: Ok sir....but cant we solve it without mathematica

Comment: More info is needed about the constants $s,\Omega_1,\Omega_2$ to ensure the integral even converges.

Comment: $s$ is the Laplace operator and $\Omega_1, \Omega_2$ are spread parameter of Nakagami distribution, which is greater than 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

Suppose $\left(m_{1},m_{2},\Omega_{1},\Omega_{2}\right)\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}^{4}\land s\in\mathbb{R}$, and assume $s<0$ to avoid singularities inside the integrand. Rescaling the integral by an arbitrary positive constant, we have

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(m_{1},m_{2};\Omega_{1},\Omega_{2};s\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}y\,y^{m_{1}-1}\exp{\left(-\frac{m_{1}}{\Omega_{1}}y\right)}\left(\frac{m_{2}}{\Omega_{2}}-sy\right)^{-m_{2}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,c(ct)^{m_{1}-1}\exp{\left(-\frac{m_{1}}{\Omega_{1}}ct\right)}\left(\frac{m_{2}}{\Omega_{2}}-sct\right)^{-m_{2}};~~~\small{\left[y=ct\land c>0\right]}\\
&=c^{m_{1}}\left(\frac{m_{2}}{\Omega_{2}}\right)^{-m_{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,t^{m_{1}-1}\exp{\left(-\frac{m_{1}}{\Omega_{1}}ct\right)}\left(1+\frac{(-s)\Omega_{2}}{m_{2}}ct\right)^{-m_{2}}\\
&=c^{m_{1}}\left(\frac{m_{2}}{\Omega_{2}}\right)^{-m_{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,t^{m_{1}-1}\exp{\left(-\frac{m_{1}}{\Omega_{1}}ct\right)}\left(1+c\frac{\Omega_{2}|s|}{m_{2}}t\right)^{-m_{2}}.\\
\end{align}$$

Choosing $c$ so that $c\frac{\Omega_{2}|s|}{m_{2}}=1$ gives us $c=\frac{m_{2}}{\Omega_{2}|s|}$. Setting $z:=\frac{m_{1}m_{2}}{\Omega_{1}\Omega_{2}}|s|^{-1}>0$, we then obtain

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(m_{1},m_{2};\Omega_{1},\Omega_{2};s\right)}
&=c^{m_{1}}\left(\frac{m_{2}}{\Omega_{2}}\right)^{-m_{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,t^{m_{1}-1}\exp{\left(-\frac{m_{1}}{\Omega_{1}}ct\right)}\left(1+c\frac{\Omega_{2}|s|}{m_{2}}t\right)^{-m_{2}}\\
&=\left(\frac{m_{2}}{\Omega_{2}}\right)^{m_{1}-m_{2}}|s|^{-m_{1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,t^{m_{1}-1}\exp{\left(-\frac{m_{1}m_{2}}{\Omega_{1}\Omega_{2}}|s|^{-1}t\right)}\left(1+t\right)^{-m_{2}}\\
&=\left(\frac{m_{2}}{\Omega_{2}}\right)^{m_{1}-m_{2}}|s|^{-m_{1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,t^{m_{1}-1}\left(1+t\right)^{-m_{2}}\exp{\left(-zt\right)}\\
&=\left(\frac{m_{2}}{\Omega_{2}}\right)^{m_{1}-m_{2}}|s|^{-m_{1}}\Gamma{\left(m_{1}\right)}\,U{\left(m_{1},m_{1}-m_{2}+1,z\right)}\\
&=\left(\frac{m_{2}}{\Omega_{2}}\right)^{m_{1}-m_{2}}\frac{\Gamma{\left(m_{1}\right)}}{(-s)^{m_{1}}}\,U{\left(m_{1},m_{1}-m_{2}+1,-\frac{m_{1}m_{2}}{\Omega_{1}\Omega_{2}s}\right)},\\
\end{align}$$

where in the last lines above $U{(a,b,z)}$ denotes the Tricomi confluent hypergeometric function, and we've made use of the following [integral representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Integral_representations):

$$U{\left(a,b,z\right)}=\frac{1}{\Gamma{\left(a\right)}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,t^{a-1}\left(1+t\right)^{-a+b-1}\exp{\left(-zt\right)};~~~\small{a>0\land z>0}.$$

---